# Why does the WAMP icon stay orange?

Tags: windows-8, wamp, google-drive

I have Windows 8, Google Drive, and WAMP with some virtual hosts configured to have a DirectoryRoot inside the Google Drive folder.

When I boot WAMP, the tray icon stays orange (it should be green when everything works), why?

Comment: What icon are you referring to?

Comment: The main WAMP icon in the tray. It is green when WAMP works, Orange when WAMP doesn't

Answer (score 2):

When you set up Google Drive, Google Drive creates a folder.

It creates this folder with only permissions for your Windows User. And no permissions for any other system program. You need to compare your Google Drive folder permissions, with another normal folder on your computer, and add all the missing permissions.

To view permissions on a folder, right click on it, select Properties. And go inside the Security "tab".

For me I ended up adding these permissions:

- Authenticated Users
- SYSTEM
- Administrators

Giving them full permission, and now WAMP boots!